# Filter by multiple checkboxes angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I've got array of objects containing STATUS field. I need to be able to filter by name, using search field, also I need to show only items with status READY, or only with status FAILED, or items with status Failed and items with status Ready. I'm using angularJs

```
    <div class="row btn-group form-group" data-toggle="buttons">
        <label class="btn btn-primary active">
            <input type="checkbox" class="form-control" ng-model="taskVm.getStateClass.taskReady">Ready
        </label>
        <label class="btn btn-primary active">
            <input type="checkbox" ng-model="taskVm.getStateClass.taskProcessing">Processing
        </label>
        <label class="btn btn-primary active">
            <input type="checkbox" ng-model="taskVm.getStateClass.taskPending">Pending
        </label>
        <label class="btn btn-primary active">
            <input type="checkbox" ng-model="taskVm.getStateClass.taskFailed">Failed
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="input-group stylish-input-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="search.REALLOCATION_NAME" placeholder="Search">
        <span class="input-group-addon">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
<ul class="tasks-list list-group">
    <li ng-repeat="task in taskVm.tasksdata | orderBy : task.ID  | filter :search | filter: taskVm.statusFilter" >
```

Here is my HTML. And here is my controller:

```
 vm.getStateClass = {   
            taskReady: 'READY',
            taskPending: 'PENDING',
            taskFailed: 'FAILED',
            taskProcessing: 'PROCESSING'
    }

     vm.statusFilter = function (task) {
         console.log(task);
        return task.STATUS === vm.getStateClass.taskReady || 
            task.STATUS === vm.getStateClass.taskPending ||
            task.STATUS === vm.getStateClass.taskFailed ||
            task.STATUS === vm.getStateClass.taskFailed;
    };
```

vm is $scope as I'm using controller As syntacsis.

Search works fine, but filtering is not working at all.

Answer (score 0):

The comparasion won't match, the checkbox will set the values of "getStateClass" to "true" or "false", so the comparasion you are making will never match. You could make the following change:

```
vm.getStateClass = {   
        taskReady: true,
        taskPending: true,
        taskFailed: true,
        taskProcessing: true
}

vm.statusFilter = function (task) {
     console.log(task);
    return task.STATUS === 'READY' && vm.getStateClass.taskReady || 
        task.STATUS === 'PENDING' && vm.getStateClass.taskPending ||
        task.STATUS === 'FAILED' && vm.getStateClass.taskFailed ||
        task.STATUS === 'PROCESSING' && vm.getStateClass.taskFailed;
};
```

```js
angular.module("app", [])
      .controller("TaskController", TaskController);

function TaskController() {
 var vm = this;

 vm.statusFilter = statusFilter;
 vm.getStateClass = {   
            taskReady: true,
            taskPending: true,
            taskFailed: true,
            taskProcessing: true
    };
    vm.tasks = [
     {
      name: 'task1',
      status: 'READY'
     }, {
      name: 'task2',
      status: 'PENDING'
     }, {
      name: 'task3',
      status: 'FAILED'
     }, {
      name: 'task4',
      status: 'PROCESSING'
     }
    ];

 function statusFilter(task) {
  return task.status === 'READY' && vm.getStateClass.taskReady
            || task.status === 'PENDING' && vm.getStateClass.taskPending
            || task.status === 'FAILED' && vm.getStateClass.taskFailed
            || task.status === 'PROCESSING' && vm.getStateClass.taskProcessing;
 }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="TaskController as taskVm">
 <label class="btn btn-primary active">
        <input type="checkbox" class="form-control" ng-model="taskVm.getStateClass.taskReady">Ready
    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-primary active">
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="taskVm.getStateClass.taskProcessing">Processing
    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-primary active">
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="taskVm.getStateClass.taskPending">Pending
    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-primary active">
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="taskVm.getStateClass.taskFailed">Failed
    </label>

    <div ng-repeat="task in taskVm.tasks | filter:taskVm.statusFilter">{{task.name}} - {{task.status}}</div>
</div>
```

Comment: At that point, since they're all true, those && conditions are completely redundant.

Comment: Yep, but the user is going to change the values of the flags by clincking on the checkbox...

Comment: Checkout the snippet, the solution I proposed is working fine, unless I understood what you were looking for wrong